# Find the general solution of an ODE with a nonlinear perturbative term

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, perturbation-theory, nonlinear-dynamics

Let's say I start with the linear differential equation

$$ y''=-y, $$

which has (for example) the two solutions $y=e^{\pm i x}$, therefore following the superposition principle the general solution is $y=a e^{ i x}+b e^{- i x}$, with $a$ and $b$ determined by the initial conditions.

Now let's say I add a perturbative term to my equation:

$$ y''=-y + \alpha y |y|^2, $$

with $\alpha$ a constant such that the new term is small compared to $y$ ($||^2$ is the absolute square). With this new equation I can still find two solutions, by assuming a solution of the form $ae^{i w x}$, I find $w\approx \pm (1 -\alpha |a|^2/2)$, defining two solutions $a e^{ i(1-\alpha |a|^2/2) x}$ and $b e^{ -i(1-\alpha |b|^2/2) x}$.

Now I would like to find the general solution to the new equation, however as it is nonlinear, I can no longer use the superposition principle. Still, as my perturbative term is small, I would expect the new general solution to be very close to the first one I obtained with the unperturbed equation (at least it should tend to it when $\alpha$ tends to zero). Is there any procedure to obtain this? I suspect there is no general procedure for any given nonlinear equation, but I thought there might be one when the nonlinearity comes from a perturbative term like here.

Numerically, I find that a linear superposition of the two special solutions is a very good approximation, at the expense of changing $w$ from $\pm (1 -\alpha |a|^2/2)$ to $\pm (1 + 0.5\alpha |a|^2/2+\epsilon)$, with $\epsilon$ to be adjusted empirically.

Comment: Do you realize you can solve this ODE exactly? Or are you only interested in the perturbative approach?

Comment: No I didn't realise, could you show me this? I'm still interested in the perturbative approach though as this is a simplified version of other similar cases I'm interested in.

Comment: Multiply both sides of the ODE by $y'$ and integrate. You get $\frac{1}{2}(y')^2=C-\frac{1}{2}y^2+\frac{1}{4}\alpha y^4$. This equation is separable.

Comment: I don't think that $y|y|^2$ is equal to $y^3$, or I missed something?

Comment: Isn't $|y|^2=y^2$?

Comment: Exact solution notwithstanding, these sorts of problems are handled in perturbation methods using multiple scales analysis, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple-scale_analysis.  In fact, the example of the Duffing oscillator on that page is almost the same as your question.

Comment: As I said in my post, $||^2$ is the absolute square ($y$ is complex in the general case). -- The Duffing oscillator example is very close indeed, thank you!

Comment: Ops, my bad! I was assuming that $y$ was real.

Comment: No problem! Thanks for the suggestion.